# Get 400 Response from Paypal when going live

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using [PayPal-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) Package. When I go live, some of my customers (not everyone) are telling me they see an error after the payment (when I try to execute).

I tested the execution in my localhost (WampServer) and it worked. It's not a problem in my credentials because the payment itself worked. The method I use is paypal. What can cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting an error of two possible reasons.

1. You didnt change the clientId and Secret of Live Environment. You should be able to find one on the developer dashboard.
2. You have not change the `mode` to `live` instead of `sandbox` in your configuration.
3. In very rare cases, you dont have the permission in live to accept payments.

You can follow instructions [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Going-Live) about [Going Live](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Going-Live).